# Tweedie distributions for large dataset, power parameter for different density peaks and random effects

Tags: mixed-model, feature-selection, interaction, high-dimensional, tweedie-distribution

I have a large dataset (343750 variables and 151 observations) and I want to model each variable as a response one in order to know if it can be explained by the group of patients and the gene expression the variable belongs to. I considered performing a non-parametric ML model (such as RF) to deal with the non-known distribution. However, I am really interested in considering the covariable gene for each variable response, specially I want to know if the interaction term of `variable~group + gene + group:gene` is relevant and compare it with the same model without the interaction `anova(model.interaction,model.nointeracion)`.

My whole set of variables have continuous and positive values (they measure the same for different gene parts) with a lot of 0s (if I calculate the % of 0's in each variable I observe two high peaks near 0 and near 100). First I thought splitting these variables into two groups (0-inflated and non-0-inflated) to fit them separately. However, reading some posts I don think it is a good idea, as the variables measure the same so even though one of them do not contain 0's it could be possible to observe one. In fact, studying some random densities I came up with the idea that a Tweedie model would be adequate, as it is a flexible model (the p parameter will define which kind of distribution would be):

```
for (i in 1:6){
plot(density(dat[,sample(343750,1)]))}
```

[image]

As you can see, some seem to be a Gamma, some an Inverse Gaussian and some show more than one peak. Obviously it is done with all the variable values, not separatedly by groups. I have also done this and sometimes still find two-peaks distributions. My idea is to model this with a loop saving the p-value obtained from the anova and may be the p-value performing a normality test of the residuals.

1. How do you see this idea? I have read in some posts that Tweedie distributions do not perform well when there is a high number of 0s, but I am really convinced it is a solution regarding the random densities with mixed distributions.
2. However, if there is a 0-peak and a right skewed peak, a power parameter between 1 and 2 would it be appropiate? (what I have understood is that these models are only appropiate for a 0-peak and will be higher than 2 if the peak is in higher values).
3. I have seen the cpglm and glm(family=tweedie(var.power=tweedie.profile())...), and the last one seems better as it automatically decides p.vec: "If NULL (the default), p.vec is set to seq(1.2, 1.8, by=0.1) if the response contains any zeros, or seq(1.5, 5, by=0.5) if the response contains no zeros. ". Would it be appropiate if I do not have 0s but it could be a possibility?
4. I would like also to add a random effect for each patient, but I have not found any package to do it with a Tweedie regression. Do you know one?

I am sorry for the lots of doubts, I am a beginner biostatistician and I have never dealed with big data.

Recommendations are of course very wellcome.

Thank you all very much in advance!

Comment: You have 343,750 variables, and you want to *"model each variable as a response"*. Have I got that right ?

Comment: Yes, you got it. I have studied some pipelines used in genomics and some implemented packages execute a model per variable in order to explain it by using the group of observations or any covariable you want. I know it is computationally demanding, but I have already done it by doing `kruskal.test(variable~group)` for each variable, but I would like to do a more sophisticated selection of variables in order to know the relevant ones by taking into account the gene. Does it make sense? I don't know any other alternative for data like this...